# Split a range into pieces that can be bitmasked

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 arbitrary 16-bit integers. As an example:

```
start: 0010000000000000 (8192)
end:   1111111111111111 (65535)
```

I would want to split the range 8192-65535 into something that can be represented with a bitmask. So in this case, I'd like to be able to identify:

```
start: 0001000000000000 (8192)
end:   0011111111111111 (16383)

start: 0100000000000000 (16384)
end:   0111111111111111 (32767)

start: 1000000000000000 (32768)
end:   1111111111111111 (65535)
```

How would I go about doing this? Not language specific, just need some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `num` is always at least 8192...

```
if num & 0xc000 == 0:
    # bitmask 0xc000 == 1100000000000000
    # first partition if the first two bits are 0
elif num & 0x8000 == 0:
    # bitmask 0x8000 == 1000000000000000
    # second partition if only the first bit is 0
else:
    # third partition
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to find all values of `2^n - 1` which are between your low and high values. This is because all block bitmasks (like the kind you are after) are of the form `2^n - 1`. Here is some python to achieve that:

```
def split_range(low, high):
    yield low
    for mask in [(1 << k) - 1 for k in xrange(0, 16) if (1 << k) > low and (1 << k) < high]:
        yield mask
    yield high
```

For you example

```
In [5]: list(split_range.split_range(8192, 65535))
Out[5]: [8192, 16383, 32767, 65535]
```